# nginx gzip did not work on php js and css processors

Tags: php, nginx, gzip, css

I have a assets manager for process css and js via php. i'm using nginx and php5-fpm for load my application. but returned css and js files not gziped.

for example my url is 
`http://mysite.com/phpcssprocessor/mycssfile.css` this file generate via php.

this is my virtual host config:

```
# /
    location / {
        # gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript application/xml text/css text/javascript text/plain text/x-component text/xml;

        # disable etag
        if_modified_since off;
        add_header 'Last-Modified' '';

        # mvc rewrite
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hit the same issue and finally solved it.

The issue was that the style.css.php file had at the top:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

And this prevented nginx from gzip-ing the file. Apparently, "gzip_type text/css" will not pick this up because of the "charset" part.

I have removed "; charset: UTF-8" from the header() argument and nginx started gziping the output.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Later I added

```
charset  UTF-8;
```

in nginx location block for that CSS processor, so I am getting the correct headers out and gzip is working.

Hope this helps somebody else as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is your php script setting the `Content-Type:` HTTP response header correctly? Does it correspond to your `gzip_types` options?
2. Is your client setting the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` HTTP request header correctly?
3. Does your relevant `http`, `server` or the `location` from which `php` is processed, include the directives for gzip compression?  When an *internal redirect* takes place through `try_files` from a `/` `location` to a `php` `location`, specifying any kind of gzip compression in the `/` `location` would be a noop — you either have to specify it globally, or in the last `location` which completes the request (intermediate locations don't affect final processing).

Without all three of the above, you won't be getting any gzip compression going.

In your specific case, it seems like the `try_files` redirect to another `location` is causing you the grief, since I see you must be specifying gzip stuff in the `/` `location` only, which is likely a noop.  Move the gzip directives outside of the `/` `location`.  You similarly may want to move your other options away from a `try_files` `/` `location` as well.

Comment: no same script works on apache php5 module. content type is text/css.

Comment: also yeas iv check headers via firebug, opera dragonfly and google chromium

Comment: seems like you don't specify gzip compression in the location which you want compressed.  i've just updated the answer after actually looking at your sample config snippet -- move your `gzip` stuff one level up from your `/` `location`, or move it into a `php` `location`, and I think it should definitely start working after that. C.